# Filter drop-shadow is causing images to blur

Tags: css, image, dropshadow

I have a png image I'd like to have a subtle drop shadow beneath. So I created a class .drop-shadow

```
img.drop-shadow{
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1));}
```

However, when I apply this class to an image then it becomes blurry. You can see a screen shot of this before and after at the link below.

[image: Screenshot of blurry image]

Is it possible to avoid this blurring? I tried block-shadow but this only works for rectangular images.

Here's the other css applied to the image just incase it is relevant.

```
img {
display: block;
max-width: 200px;
width: 100%;
margin: 1rem auto;
margin-bottom: $body-line-height;
padding-top: 0;}
```

Here's a codepen to make it a bit easier
http://codepen.io/patrickaltair/pen/cHsbj

Comment: If you don't want blurring don't use the `<blur-radius>` value (the third 3px). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: I tried changing the <blur-radius> value to zero and getting rid of it entirely but it seems to just effect how dissipated the drop shadow is and unfortunately the image remains blurry.

Comment: Perhaps a Jsfiddle Demo with the actual image?

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj5r81u9/1/) with your code (different image). But it doesn't seem to blur the image. Are you using a very big image that's being resized with CSS? Is the image blurred in all browsers? BTW, the blur-radius value  (the third `3px` adds blur to the shadow, not to the image.

Comment: @patrick.altair What browser are you on? It looks fine to me

Comment: I've made a codepen with the actual image here: http://codepen.io/patrickaltair/pen/cHsbj
The photo is not particularly large 400x588 and around 600kb. Johanpw the second image on your fiddle does appear blurry on my screen. The screenshot is from chrome but appears blurry in safari as well. Perhaps it is because my screen is a retina display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the `-webkit` filters on Retina screens.

Quick fix: Add this to your css file:

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

I can't test if it's working, as I don't have a retina screen, but please let me know if it does.

Comment: For me, chrome didn't accept the -webkit- prefix, after removing it, the image remained blurry after the transform whereas before it was only blurry while the image was generating the box shadow transition.